# MinGW x86_64-w64-mingw32 b2 build boost library from source. cannot find link library

Tags: c++, mingw

I try to build boost libraries for windows and got some errors.
boost version boost_1_75_0  version 1.75.

MinGW comes with Codeblocks I got from

codeblocks-20.03mingw-setup.exe

my windows also installed python39.

Python bin(c:\python39\bin), MingW\bin (c:\codeblocks\MingW\bin) and boost install (c:\boost\bin) are in search path.

boost source code was in f:\src\boost_1_75_0

cd to f:\src\boost_1_75_0\tools\build
run

bootstrap.bat gcc

b2 toolset=gcc --prefix=C:\boost --build-type=complete install

cd to f:\src\boost_1_75_0\ and run
b2 toolset=gcc --prefix=C:\boost release debug inlining=off debug-symbols=on --with-filesystem --with-program_options --build-type=complete install

ERROR:

x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
cannot find -lstdc++

x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwthrd.a when searching for -lmingwthrd

x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmingwthrd

x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libgcc_s.a when searching for -lgcc_s

x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc_s

x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc

x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc

Answer (score 0):

MinGW that comes with Code::Blocks is a bit old.
I recommend using MinGW-w64.
There is a standalone build of MinGW-w64 available from http://winlibs.com/ and the site also explains how to configure Code::Blocks to use it.